# JQUERY copy contents of a textbox to a field while typing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to copy the contents of a textbox into a div simultaneously while the user is typing. Here is [THE CODE ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6HmxM/)
The error that is am facing is, **the length of the value copied inside the div is always one less than that of the textbox**. what error am i making in the script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead.

```
$("#boxx").keyup(function(event) {
  var stt = $(this).val();
  $("div").text(stt);
});
```

`keypress` occurs when the key is pressed down and you want the text transferred when the key is released.

Comment: Note @Rahat's answer if you care about copying changes from pasted text as well.

Comment: keyup function itself works for copying changes from pasted text.

Answer (score 13):

The **keyup** and **keypress** events work for keyboard input, but if one uses the mouse to right-click and paste something into the text box then the value change will not be picked up. You can use `bind` with the **input** event to register both **keyup** and paste events like this:

```
$("#textbox1").bind('input', function () {
   var stt = $(this).val();
   $("#textbox2").val(stt);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The `keypress` event occurs before the text in the `<input>` element is updated. You can delay the copy operation to work around that. Even a 0 millisecond delay will be enough for the copy operation to occur after the  element is updated:

```
$("#boxx").keypress(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       $("div").text($this.val());
    }, 0);
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6HmxM/4/).

Comment: Another good reason for using your method is it handles Cut and Paste much better, whereas with .keyup the delay is very noticeable for these instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#title").keypress(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                window.setTimeout(function() {

                   $("#slug-url").val($this.val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-'));
                }, 0);
            });
```

using @Frédéric Hamidi' method to generate seo friendly url after replacing spaces with '-' and changing text to smallcase.

Answer (score 0):

use keyup and change both.

```
$("#boxx").on('keypress change', function(event) {
       var data=$(this).val();
       $("div").text(data);
});
```

here is the example
http://jsfiddle.net/6HmxM/785/

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#boxx").keyup(function() {
    var $this= $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       $("div").text($this.val());
    }, 0);
});
```

this work proper.

Copy also works f9`enter code here`