# How to implement a typeahead like Houzz?

Tags: javascript, search, typeahead.js

I want to implement a typeahead for my search similar to the one found on [Houzz](http://www.houzz.com.au/).
Does anyone know of a plugin that will accomplish this? I'm currently using typeahead.js with Bootstrap 3.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found all my answers in this question, [jquery-copy-contents-of-a-textbox-to-a-field-while-typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160076/jquery-copy-contents-of-a-textbox-to-a-field-while-typing)

I figured out all the function is doing is cloning the value of the search input into a list of categories. Once I understood this I knew what to search for.

In the end, I triggered the drop-down to appear on the search input `.keypress()` and then I cloned the `.val()` in to the search suggestions text and href.

**Update:** I ended up using `.bind()` instead of `.keypress()` because keypress wont register a mouse interaction like mouse - paste into search field